# Nested foreach to display over rows

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, foreach

In C# I am trying to do a nested `foreach` to display a list of articles. The flat HTML I have been given requires a `<div class="row">` for every 3 articles.

My original code to simply display the articles looks like this:

```
@foreach (var article in Model)
        {

            <div class="spanthird col">
                <div class="well">
                    <article>
                        <h3>@article.UrlStringDisplay</h3>
                        <div class="date">@article.Date.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")</div>
                        <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("PressReleases", new {id = article.UrlString, Action = "article", Controller = "PressReleases"})" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</a>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

I want to include the div class="row" for every 3 articles. I've got to this point but its 'spazzing' out on the 'data' in the first `foreach`.

```
   int i = 0;
foreach (var row in )
{
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        @:<div class="row">
    }

    foreach (var article in Model)
        {

            <div class="spanthird col">
                <div class="well">
                    <article>
                        <h3>@article.UrlStringDisplay</h3>
                        <div class="date">@article.Date.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")</div>
                        <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("PressReleases", new {id = article.UrlString, Action = "article", Controller = "PressReleases"})" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</a>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>
        }

    if (i % 3 == 2 || i == data.Count() - 1)
    {
        @:</div>
    }
    i++;
}
```

I am almost there. I just need a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: `foreach (var row in ????)` what's supposed to be there? What do you mean spazzing out? I could see it not liking the fact that there's nothing after the `in` :)

Comment: Updated and added data

Comment: What are you doing with your HTML? It's not printed out or saved in any variable.

Answer (score 3):

This is the cleanest I can think of:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i+=3)
{
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var article in Model.Skip(i).Take(3))
        {
            <div class="spanthird col">
                <div class="well">
                    <article>
                        <h3>@article.UrlStringDisplay</h3>
                        <div class="date">@article.Date.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")</div>
                        <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("PressReleases", new {id = article.UrlString, Action = "article", Controller = "PressReleases"})" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</a>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>                
        }
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u are going too complex on it
  try this :

```
        int row = 1;
        @foreach (var article in Model)
        {
            @if(row == 1)
                @:<div class="row">
            <div class="spanthird col">
                <div class="well">
                    <article>
                        <h3>@article.UrlStringDisplay</h3>
                        <div class="date">@article.Date.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")</div>
                        <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("PressReleases", new {id = article.UrlString, Action = "article", Controller = "PressReleases"})" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</a>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>
            @if(row == 3)
                @:</div>
            <% row++; %>
            @if(row == 4)
                <% row = 1; %>
        }
        @if(i != 1)
             @:</div>
```

Comment: This has a slight bug - if the items are say 5, the second `<div class="row">` won't have a closing tag.

Comment: I get this error for this code Parser Error Message: Expected a "{" but found a "@".  Block statements must be enclosed in "{" and "}".  You cannot use single-statement control-flow statements in CSHTML pages.